# remove_accents does not seem to work (when used inside sanitize_file_name filter)

Tags: uploads, sanitization

I am trying to automatically remove accents from uploaded files through WP administration. This is my current approach (`functions.php`):

```
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', function($filename) {
    return strtolower(remove_accents($filename));
});
```

This does not provide the desired result though. JPEG with filename `ČF_Hajská.jpg`:

- desired result: `cf_hajska.jpg`
- real result: `čf_hajská.jpg`

I've tried to use `remove_accents` function outside the filter and it worked as expected (`ČF_Hajská.jpg` => `CF_Hajska.jpg`).

Am I overlooking something obvious?

I am using WordPress 5.3.2 (which appears to be a current version).

Answer (score 0):

I've just got an advice on Twitter from [Daniel Střelec](https://twitter.com/DanielStrelec) to simply use `sanitize_title` - which is a better solution anyway, as it removes whitespace and other non-ideal characters for filename. Use it this way:

`add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'sanitize_title');`

I'm keeping the question opened though, as what I've described above sounds like a WP bug to me.

## Edit (important!)

Do not use `sanitize_title` for this purpose! It *does* remove accents, however it replaces dots with dashes which invalidates image URLs.

`image.jpg => image-jpg`

This is my current implementation:

```
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', function($file_name_full) {
    $file_info = pathinfo($file_name_full);

    $file_name = sanitize_title($file_info['filename']);
    $file_ext = $file_info['extension'];

    $result = "${file_name}.${file_ext}";
    return $result;
}, 11);
```

Also - `pathinfo($filepath)['filename']` is supported since PHP 5.2.0, so watch out for that (but you should use current version of PHP anyway).